# How to modify/adapt methods from API library?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, multipleselection, statelistdrawable

I'm using [**Big Nerd Ranch's recyclerview-multiselect**](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect) library to give my `RecyclerView`'s `CardViews` a multi-selection capability.  I've worked out my app-specific kinks for the most part, but I ran into a pretty big issue. Whenever the `RecyclerView` is in `SelectionMode` **and** has to recreate a card (which is often, because that's practically the point of `RecyclerView`, at least if I understand it correctly,) it throws this error:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: android.graphics.drawable.StateListDrawable cannot be cast to android.support.v7.widget.RoundRectDrawableWithShadow
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getShadowBackground(CardViewEclairMr1.java:159)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardViewEclairMr1.getMinWidth(CardViewEclairMr1.java:150)
        at android.support.v7.widget.CardView.onMeasure(CardView.java:181)
        at android.view.View.measure(View.java:16498)
```

Logically, I followed the error to whatever source was causing a StateListDrawable to be set as the `CardView`'s background. What I found was summed up by [a commented section in **this class**](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect/blob/7519d47e66898d68bf33cd720a3b3ea0290c6fe5/recyclerview-multiselect/src/main/java/com/bignerdranch/android/multiselector/SwappingHolder.java). It reads as follows:

> selectionModeBackgroundDrawable defaults to a StateListDrawable that displays your colorAccent theme color when state_activated=true, and nothing otherwise.

In the `SwappingHolder` class, you can see where the `StateListDrawable`, causing the error, is being returned. Also, if you look in the `CardViewEclairMr1.java`, as suggested in the error, you can see the method that most directly causes the error:

```
private RoundRectDrawableWithShadow getShadowBackground(CardViewDelegate cardView) {
        return ((RoundRectDrawableWithShadow) cardView.getBackground());
    }
```

To be honest, after all this snooping around in the [BigNerdRanch library](https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect), I'm still not sure what to do! I was thinking I might need to `@Override` the BigNerdRanch methodology which brings in a `StateListDrawable`, but that would be getting my hands so dirty with the library, it would defeat the purpose of implementing their API to begin with. How do I fix this error?

Answer (score 1):

A little late with the answer but here is something that I found and that worked for me.
Check to see if your CardView layout is wrapped inside a ViewGroup and if is not that might be the problem.

SwappingHolder works by swapping out the drawables of the top-level View. CardView uses its own drawables, so it will not work if you use it as the top-level View.
So the right way is this
`<FrameLayout
    ...
    >
    <CardView 
        ...
        >
    </CardView>
</FrameLayout>`
Or you can implement the SelectableHolder interface yourself, and choose how you want to display a selected item.
All these are the authors words  <strike>so here is a [link to GitHub][link] to the actual page

[link]:https://github.com/bignerdranch/recyclerview-multiselect/issues/14.</strike>  
Good luck !